# How do I scale Azure Data Factory Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I was able to setup a SCD Type 2 process quite easily using the ADF UI for one table BUT I don't see an easy way to scale to the 1000s of datasources we've. I don't see any Java APIs that will allow me to write ADF Pipelines/Dataflow and configure & trigger them dynamically. No UI to allow which tables to choose from a particular database etc. I looked at Azure Datalake Gen 2, Azure Databricks etc. I don't see any tool in Azure that will allow us to replace the UI driven Data Lake ingestion process we've built in house. Am I missing something?

On a side note, we've an old Data lake application that ingests data from thousands of datasources such as Databases, log files, web applications etc and stores data on HDFS (a typical architecture) using technologies as Java, Spark, Kafka etc. We're evaluating Azure Active Data Factory to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic SCD (Type 1, but you can retrofit to Type 2) example built into ADF. Go to New > Pipeline from template > Transform with Data flows > Generic SCD Type 1.

This pattern is outlined here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/create-generic-scd-pattern-in-adf-mapping-data-flows/ba-p/918519.

You can also iterate over schemaless table datasets for Foreach inside a pipeline, calling the same data flow on every iteration.

Lastly, if you still wish to stamp-out data flows programmatically, the .NET and PowerShell SDKs are listed in the references section of the online Azure docs.

Comment: Schemaless tables? That's not the requirement so that's not enough! Yes, I noticed that there's .NET but no Java SDK. In any case, it seems scaling to 1000s of tables is NOT out of the box in Azure. It does require lot of coding.

Comment: Schemaless datasets of type SQL Table allow you to generalize your data flows by parameterizing the tables. Since data flow doesn't care about schema with a schemaless dataset, you can make a generic pattern. I explain this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj15Yjwai1A

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the REST API from Java to build out pipelines using code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api